# How do I use the "this" keyword in java?

Tags: java, this

I've been using multiple methods, but my "java the complete reference" book doesn't do a good job of explaining how to use the "this" keyword.

Comment: Look at the tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: I'd be surprised if _the complete reference_ didn't explain `this`.

Comment: it's used for the constructor, correct ?  it's used a lot good 2 know *this* , * ahem *

Answer (score 1):

this in java

It is used to refer to the data members of the object in the envoked method or constructor in case there is a name conflict between fields and local variables

```
    public class Test {
    String s;
    int i; 
    public Test(String s, int i){
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    } }
```

It is used to invoke one constructor from another constructor of the same class or you can say constructor chaining.

```
public class ConstructorChainingEg{
    String s;
    int i;
    public ConstructorChainingEg(String s, int i){
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
        System.out.println(s+" "+i);
    }
    public ConstructorChainingEg(){
        this("abc",3); // from here call goes to parameterized constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ConstructorChainingEg m = new ConstructorChainingEg();
      // call goes to default constructor
    }
}
```

It also facilitates method chaining

```
class Swapper{
    int a,b;
    public Swapper(int a,int b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    public Swapper swap() {
        int c=this.a;
        this.a=this.b;
        this.b=c;
        return this;
    }
    public static void main(String aa[]){
        new Swapper(4,5).swap(); //method chaining
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `main` method in the last example, you could maybe assign the `Swapper` to a variable (or do something similar), such that the line `return this` has a use.

Comment: So "this" is used for more than one constructor? If so, then why would you need more than one constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple:

```
public class Example {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    // use it to differentiate between local and class variables
    public Example(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    // use it to chain constructors
    public Example() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    // revised answer:
    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return this.b
    }

    public int setA(int a) {
        this.a = a
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

`this` refers to the attributes that belong to the object in which `this` is used in. For example:

```
Example ex1 = new Example(3,4);
Example ex2 = new Example(8,1);
```

In these cases, `ex1.getA()` will return 3, because `this` is referring to the `a` that belongs to the object named `ex1`, and not `ex2` or anything else. The same goes for `ex2.getB()`.

If you look at the `setA()` and `setB()` methods, using `this` distinguishes the attributes `a` and `b` belonging to the object from the parameter names as they're the same.

Comment: can you explain what the "this" keyword is used for? I don't know what to do with it

Comment: `this` is a reference to itself

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is "itself"

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer